# Binary XML error inflating class in Xamarin AccountKit

Tags: xamarin.android, account-kit

I have been using AccountKit wrapper of Naxam for Xamarin.Android without problems with the latest package version from NuGet. Recently the library started throwing `InflateException` upon initiating SMS authentication on new builds. The exact exception content is as follows:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.project.droid/com.facebook.accountkit.ui.AccountKitActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML
>   file line #19: Error inflating class TextView

Up to now I have tried the below steps recommended for similar problems on SO:

1. I cleaned the project
2. I deleted `bin` and `obj` folders
3. I restarted Visual Studio
4. I tried building with older versions of Naxam AccountKit on NuGet

Unfortunately none of them helped. What could be the problem?

Comment: When you are compiling your project, does the output give any warnings of mismatched package versions?

Comment: It gives this warning albeit unrelated to AccountKit's package: No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.

Comment: That is indicating mismatched packages or assembly refs somewhere. I would go to your Tools->Options->Projects_and_Solutions->Build_and_Run->MSBuild_project_build_output_verbosity and look into see what is causing this error.

Comment: Frankly I'm struggling to resolve the conflict in mscorlib.dll. Even when I set build output to Diagnostic, it only writes the exact same line regarding this. What else should I be checking there? @uprightbassfan78